# Find a polynomial $Q$ of degree $k$ and a remainder function $E$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

There is a theorem in our textbook saying that rather than calculating all the derivatives needed to compute the taylor polynomial, if one can find, by any means, a polynomial $Q$ of degree $k$ such that $\dfrac{f(a+h)-Q(h)}{|h|}\to 0$, then $Q$ must be the taylor polynomial.

And the question is to use this method to find the polynomial $Q$ of degree $k$ for the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ near $0$.

I understand this theorem but I just don't know what I should start with. I'd rather find the taylor polynomial by calculating all the derivatives needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the remarkable identity:
$$1-x^{n+1}=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)$$
and rewrite it so as to obtain:$$\frac 1{1-x}=\dots$$